# Get the execution result of a file.php via xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I'm calling a file.php using XMLHttpRequest in javascript:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function(){ 
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        };

        xhr.open("GET", "file.php", true);
        xhr.send();

</script>
```

**file.php**

```
<?php echo "123";
```

---

I expected `123` as result string but instead I got `<?php echo "123";` which is the file.php content.

Am I using the `XMLHttpRequest` right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your server isn't set up correctly and isn't executing the script with the PHP parser.

What happens when you request the page without XMLHttpRequest (ie, just enter the url in the browser)?

Comment: I think you're right, it's something with the server. The browser download the file insteat of parsing it, thank you. I'll check what's wrong